# Q:How to filter kendo-grid data by using checkbox?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Is there a way to filter kendo grid data by using checkbox?
Sample grid-data

```js
var defaultData = [{
  clientName: "Jupiter-RTU-0B40",
  clientTypeID: 1,
  clientType: "PrimaryProbe",
  SystemTypeID: 5,
  SystemTypeName: "TEMS Automatic",
  lastUpdate: "28d",
  location: "3.08191833333333,101.58238",
  status: "InProcess",
  groups: [1, 2]
}, {
  clientName: "RTU0010F3360B40",
  clientTypeID: 2,
  clientType: "Probe",
  SystemTypeID: 5,
  SystemTypeName: "TEMS Automatic",
  lastUpdate: "28d",
  location: "3.08191833333333,101.58238",
  status: "Pending",
  groups: [1, 2]
}, {
  clientName: "MPC00200C6C2ACE",
  clientTypeID: 1,
  clientType: "PrimaryProbe",
  SystemTypeID: 5,
  SystemTypeName: "TEMS Automatic",
  lastUpdate: "82d",
  location: "63.7443,19.9584",
  status: "InProcess",
  groups: [1, 2]
}, {
  clientName: "RTU0010F33FDBD8",
  clientTypeID: 1,
  clientType: "PrimaryProbe",
  SystemTypeID: 5,
  SystemTypeName: "TEMS Automatic",
  lastUpdate: "0d",
  location: "3.08191833333333,101.58238",
  status: "InProcess",
  groups: [1, 2]
}, {
  clientName: "RTU0010F33FDBD8",
  clientTypeID: 2,
  clientType: "Probe",
  SystemTypeID: 6,
  SystemTypeName: "TEMS Automatic",
  lastUpdate: "0d",
  location: "3.08191833333333,101.58238",
  status: "Pending",
  groups: [1, 2]
}]
```

For example,I have a list of check box where it allow user to check/uncheck. An example like lastUpdate is uncheck then the grid will be showing all the data accordingly except lastUpdate.

Comment: could you please elaborate your scenario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For getting a boolean filter you have to define the datasource model. You can set there your field type to boolean, so kendo will display a boolean filter.